# ESXi - serial console as default console

Tags: vmware-esxi, console, serial

I have headless Supermicro server with IPMI as my ESXi 5 but I would like to use serial console as default console for ESXi instead of accessing it via IPMI VGA console redirection. I have some problems with java with IPMI and I also prefer text ui :)

I tried to follow [Redirect the Direct Console to a Serial Port Using the vSphere Client](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50%2FGUID-E17AB108-7AA0-43DF-8616-48625CD018DF.html) but no success.

My goal is:

- see in serial port boot loader of ESXi (it is syslinux what I see)
- see booting via serial port (not logging but internactive stuff)
- see shell which I can use to login via serial port

My server has serial console. Next step would be to setup IPMI SOL.

Can anybody share how to do it? The procedure above didn't work for me.

How to check that ESXi was booting with serial port as console?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? why not just use the powercli or equivilants?

Comment: You didn't get it at all :DDDD You confuse CLI with console.

Comment: I can assure you I know the difference, I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: As I don't have any display plugged with my ESXi server, I'm accessing it via IPMI VGA console redirection. But this needs java and java is crap, sometimes it doesn't work with specific java version etc. So I would prefer serial console as primary console. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_console

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Once you've installed ESXi, there's very little reason to access the console of your host server. You can enable ssh if necessary and use that.

Comment: Very little reason but still there's reason, like troubleshooting booting, getting output from host's kernel panic etc...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work? Still not sure why you want to follow this path, but the option is available.

> **Redirect the Direct Console to a Serial Port Using the vSphere Client**
>
> When you use the vSphere Client to redirect the direct console to a
>   serial port, the boot option you set persists after subsequent
>   reboots.
>
> You can redirect the direct console to either of the serial ports com1
>   or com2.
>
> The serial port must not be in use for serial logging and debugging,
>   or for ESX Shell (tty1Port). Prerequisites
>
> 1. Verify that you can access the host from the vSphere Client. The
>      serial port must not already be in use for serial logging and
>      debugging, or for ESX Shell (tty1Port).
> 2. From the vSphere Client, connect to the vCenter Server and select the
>      host in the inventory.
> 3. Click the Configuration tab.
> 4. Under Software, click Advanced Settings.
> 5. In the left pane, expand the VMkernel listing and select Boot.
> 6. Make sure that the VMkernel.Boot.logPort and VMkernel.Boot.gdbPort
>      fields are not set to use the com port that you want to redirect the
>      direct console to.
> 7. Set VMkernel.Boot.tty2Port to the serial port to redirect the direct
>      console to: com1 or com2.
> 8. Click OK.
>
> Reboot the host.
>
> You can now manage the ESXi host remotely from a console connected to
>   the serial port.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.install.doc_50%2FGUID-C65306C0-DA37-4F45-8A50-31F8D109BB1D.html